# iphone: appID creation problem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, distribution, app-id

Whenever I create an app ID on my provisioning profile, the 10 digit bundle seed ID keeps getting imported in front of it... e.g. YVW2UMA3HV.com.yourcompany.ytj

..As a result, the project i'm trying to compile (which as bundleID com.yourcompany.ytj gives an error in Application Loader.

..Is there a way to create an appID without the 'YVW2UMA3HV' in front of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior and always worked for me. 
Have you, however, tried using something different than "com.yourcompany" as prefix? Because that's where the problem might be at.

Comment: my provisioning profile (imported into xcode organizer) has an applicationidentifer of:7YH5AA3D9M.com.devinpigera.YouTubeJunki  ...So what do I type in my bundle identifer? is it just "com.devinpigera.YouTubeJunki" ? or "7YH5AA3D9M.com.devinpigera.YouTubeJunki" ?

Answer (score 0):

The value you supply in your Xcode project for the Identifier property of the target is just the com.yourcomparny.whatever portion of the AppID.